# How to copy files synced using azure files to a new azure storage location?

Tags: azure, azure-storage-files, azure-files

I have mapped my azure storage files in my local machine's network drive. now I want to copy the file from azures shared files location to a new location in azure storage whenever a new file is pasted in local machines network drive.

I followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows) to mount azure files in my local machine.

Can anyone help me with copying those files from shared location to a new location in azure storage account?

What are the different approaches to achieve this scenario?

Comment: This is a fairly broad question. And unclear whether you're copying to another area in your file share or to a discrete blob, both requiring different approaches (one is file I/O, one is file I/O + storage REST/SDK call). And how you implement your watcher is up to you (and specific to the OS you're using).

Comment: This has the [azure-functions] tag, but the problem statement sounds like it's not related to AzureFunctions.  Can you either update the question (if it's related to AzureFunctions) or remove that tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to copy the file from azures shared files location to a new location in azure storage whenever a new file is pasted in local machines network drive.

It seems that you [mount your Azure File share on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows) and you'd like to monitor file additions/changes to local machine network drive and copy new file to another area (file share or blob).

You can try this approach: create and run a [FileTrigger WebJob](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions) on your local machine to detect whether new files arrive, and use [Azure Storage Services REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/azure-storage-services-rest-api-reference) or Microsoft Azure Storage Client Library to programmatic access and copy the new file to another file share or blob.